# how many class is here in only one COM?

Tags: com

every one.
      We know that COM server exsits as dll or ax. We can use COM component through calling CoCreateInstance.  you known that each COM class has a CLSID. we use CLSID to create a object. I want to answer that how many COM classes can implement in one dll(COM server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single .dll file (in-proc COM server) can serve any sane number of COM classes - we have a commercial product that is shipped with a single COM server implementing something like twenty COM classes.

The fact that Windows registry will map multiple class ids onto the same .dll file isn't a problem - there's `DllGetClassObject()` function in every in-proc COM server that is passed the class id requested and retrieves the right class factory. So a single in-proc COM server cam serve multiple COM classes.

Comment: do you mean that many com classes (CLSID) store in one dll. there have two items in registry like follow: CLSID_one addresss D:/myCom.dll CLSID_two address D:/myCom.dll

Comment: @kenny: Yes, that's surely possible. The fact that both class ids map onto the same .dll is not a problem - `DllGetClassObject()` inside the .dll will retrieve the right class factory.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see completely.